# Continue slideDown() after being stopped midway?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

How do I let a `slideDown()` animation continue, after I have previously stopped it (or `slideUp()`) midway? I believe the fact that it won't, has to do with the fact that `slideDown()` only acts on elements that are initially hidden. And elements in the midst of these animations are not hidden.

Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour, and have jQuery continue animating after being stopped? (Edit: or if you know of an alternative solution to using `slideDown()`; that will do as well of course)

Please view [my jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ETQeC/) as well, to see what I'm trying to do.

---

As for a little background information:
I want to implement this behaviour for form validation messages. I individually slide them down, and after a delay, slide them up again. But if a user resubmits the form quicker than the messages disappear and certain "new" messages are already present and have not finished animating (either sliding up or down), I want to slide them down again.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you can [hide it before sliding down again](http://jsfiddle.net/Nuam9/) I suppose?

Comment: @Antony Wow, that is actually deceptively simple. However, if the element had completed its animation already, it restarts the complete animation again. ([See this edit I made](http://jsfiddle.net/BCCew/1/) of your suggestion.) I want to avoid this. So, if you have a clever solution to that problem as well, put it in an answer. Then, I will do some further tests with it, and award you the bonus if it does the job.

Comment: http://jqapi.com/#p=stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicate whether the `slideDown` is completed in `.data()`. If it is not completed due to the `stop` function, `hide` it and `slideDown` again.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GRRhy/1/)**.

```
$( 'div' ).hide().slideDown(1000, function() {
    $(this).data("completed", "completed");
});
setTimeout( function() {
    $( 'div' ).stop( true );
}, 500 );
setTimeout( function() {
    if ($('div').data("completed") !== "completed") {
        $( 'div' ).hide().slideDown();
    }
}, 2000 );
```

Comment: Yeah, this is basically it. I'm gonna use `.data()`, in stead of `.attr()`, but that's a minor detail. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot I can't award you the bounty yet; I have to wait another 22 hours, unfortunately. Coming your way tomorrow then.

Comment: Thanks. Glad that I can help. You are right I should use `.data()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is to use .stop() before your animation, e.g.

```
$('#element').stop().slideUp();
```

Check out jQuery's example at http://api.jquery.com/stop/

And let me know if you need more help or clarification on this :)

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't do anything for me. Which example are you referring to? The last one? If so, that one use `slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmUZs/1/) ?

```
$( 'div' ).hide().slideDown( 1000 );
setTimeout( function() {
    $( 'div' ).stop( true );
    $( 'div' ).hide().slideDown(1000);
}, 500 );
```

For `slideUp()` in midway, remove the `hide()`

```
$( 'div' ).hide().slideDown( 1000 );
setTimeout( function() {
    $( 'div' ).stop( true );
    $( 'div' ).slideUp(1000);
}, 500 );
```